# Is it possible to include tabs within tabs in Angular material design

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

```
<md-tabs class="md-primary">
  <md-tab label="1">
    <md-tab-label>Step 1)</md-tab-label>
    <md-tab-body>
      <md-tabs>
        <md-tab label="1sub">
          <md-tab-label>Tab within tab</md-tab-label>
          <md-tab-body>
            Some tab data
          </md-tab-body>
        </md-tab>
      </md-tabs>
    </md-tab-body>
  </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

Is it possible to create tabs within tabs? The most simple example (pardon the nesting) above doesn't really work, the "sub tabs" won't render properly. Label won't work and the content is not shown.

Comment: It's probably just CSS issues as directive should work just alright

Comment: The child md-tabs inherits properties from the parent, also "Some tab data" isn't present in the dom so should be more than just CSS-issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer - Yes.

I had the same question, and didn't have any problem getting this working:

```html
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="BlankApp" ng-cloak>
  <div>
    <h1>Tab Demo</h1>
    <md-content class="md-padding">
      <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-stretch-tabs>
        <md-tab label="Top Level 1">
          <h3>Top Level 1 Content</h3>
          <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-stretch-tabs style="padding-left: 5em;">
            <md-tab label="Sub-Level 1">
              <h4>Top1 Sub1 Content</h4>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab label="Sub-Level 2">
              <h4>Top1 Sub2 Content</h4>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab label="Sub-Level 3">
              <h4>Top1 Sub3 Content</h4>
            </md-tab>
          </md-tabs>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="Top Level 2">
          <h3>Top Level 2 Content</h3>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="Top Level 3">
          <h3>Top Level 3 Content</h3>
          <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-stretch-tabs style="padding-left: 5em;">
            <md-tab label="Sub-Level 1">
              <h4>Top3 Sub1 Content</h4>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab label="Sub-Level 2">
              <h4>Top3 Sub2 Content</h4>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab label="Sub-Level 3">
              <h4>Top3 Sub3 Content</h4>
            </md-tab>
          </md-tabs>
        </md-tab>
      </md-tabs>
    </md-content>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  
  <!-- Your application bootstrap  -->
  <script type="text/javascript">    
    /**
     * You must include the dependency on 'ngMaterial' 
     */
    angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial']);
  </script>
  
</body>
</html>

<!--
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. 
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be in foundin the LICENSE file at http://material.angularjs.org/license.
-->
```

That should get you going.

Cheers,
Dan

Comment: @DanielLobo That is an incorrect statement. You may have the tab with sub-tabs nested anywhere along the tabbed layout. I have updated my code snippet above to show the nested tabs appearing at both the first and the last top level item.  -D.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that nested tabs are explicitly not supported in Material Design. Refer to [Material Design - Tabs component](https://material.io/guidelines/components/tabs.html#tabs-usage)'s last example or this github discussion: [setting class on nested tabs](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3703#issuecomment-137818694)

You should consider another approach !